# Scheme define/lambda shorthand

Tags: lambda, scheme

In Scheme, how can I make use of the define/lambda shorthand for nested lambda expressions within my define?

For example given the following procedure...

```
(define add
  (lambda (num1 num2)
    (+ num1 num2)))
```

One can shorten it to this:

```
(define (add num1 num2)
  (+ num1 num2))
```

However, how can I shorten the following function similarly ?

```
(define makeOperator
  (lambda (operator)
    (lambda (num1 num2)
      (operator num1 num2))))

;example useage - equivalent to (* 3 4):
((makeOperator *) 3 4)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(define (makeOperator operator)
  (lambda (num1 num2)
    (operator num1 num2)))
```

The second lambda can not be shortened.

Well you could shorten it to `(define (makeOperator operator) operator)`, if you don't want to enforce that the returned function takes exactly two arguments.

Comment: Thanks - I'll +1 you once my vote limit resets :). http://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/start.html#g1642 - if you scroll down a bit, the author seems to be talking about some kind of dot syntax for shortening defines. Any idea what he's talking about?

Comment: @incrediman: Yes, he's talking about `(define (f . xs) ...)` which will allow you to call f with an arbitrary number of arguments (e.g. `(f 1 2 3 4 5)`) and `xs` will be a list containing those arguments.

Comment: Ahhh. Gotcha - thanks. That's actually quite useful itself, so I'm glad I asked :)

Answer (score 7):

Some implementations of Scheme -- like Guile (tested with version 1.8) and MIT Scheme -- provide the following shorthand notation:

```
(define ((foo x) y) (+ x y))

(foo 5)
; => procedure
((foo 5) 3)
; => 8
```

I believe this notation is used quite a lot in [Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicm/).

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to the above answer, the second `lambda` *can* use the shorthand `define` notation:

```
(define (makeOperator operator)
  (define (foo num1 num2)
    (operator num1 num2))
  foo)
```

Comment: It's not really the same thing. In my simpler shorthand, no extra variables are declared, but here you're declaring foo. So while it does use the define syntax, it is not really shorthand. Plus it's longer than the lambda version by sepp2k. /end relatively uneducated opinion

Comment: (a) I didn't say that it's shorter -- only that it uses the *shorthand* `define` form which is what you asked about; (b) your question was whether it's possible to use this notation for an internal `lambda` -- obviously, this would come with an extra name because that's exactly what `define` does: there's no way to use it without a name.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, if your goal is to just make it short, then as sepp2k said you can use `(define (makeOperator operator) operator)`, and if you really want to go all the way: `(define makeOperator values)` is roughly the same.

Comment: @Eli: I think he might have been looking for something like `(define ((makeOperator operator) num1 num2) operator num1 num2)`, i.e. curried function definition, which does not exist in scheme (but could probably be implemented with a macro).

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, that's what I was looking for - thanks. @Eli: On second thought this actually does answer my question fairly well, even though it's not exactly what I was looking for, so +1. Also I do realize that my trivial example can be simplified :) Thanks.

Comment: @incrediman: Yeah, I though it would help to clarify the difference.  Also, I suspect that the curried definition that sepp2k mentioned (and Michal made into an answer) is closer to what you'd want -- *but* if you're at that level of getting to know the language, it's best to avoid it for now.  It will only make things confusing.  (And you can easily get back to it when you're more fluent.)

Comment: @Eli Related to this discussion, is it possible to eliminate the use of one or both lambdas in the definition of **permute** in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180101/creating-an-n-sized-permutation-with-scheme-using-only-basic-constructs/10898713#10898713)?

Comment: @lifebalance: Yes -- note that in general you can always turn a `lambda` into a `define` -- but the result is more verbose, so it's not useful in practice.  The real point of this is that you don't need *anonymous* functions in order to have a language with first-class functions -- and in face, `lambda` could be defined as a macro that uses `define`.

Comment: @Eli Verbosity also sometimes makes it more readable? Could you show me how to rewrite **permute** without the lambdas? Thanks,

Comment: @lifebalance: that won't work in a comment, send me an email and I'll explain more.  (Or maybe start a new question if that's easier.)